# TreeView WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm using `TreeView` WPF.
I have the following class:

```
class MyFiles : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     public string displayName;
     public string fullPath;

     public string DisplayName
     {
         get{return displayName;}
         set{displayName = value; INofityPropertyChanged();}
     }
      public string FullName
     {
         get{return fullPath;}
         set{fullPath = value; INofityPropertyChanged();}
     }

     private void INofityPropertyChanged(string propertyName="")
     {
        if(propertyName != null && PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventsArgs(propertyName);
     }
}
```

I want to binding the class to TreeView.
What i'm tried:

```
<TreeView Name=treeViewFiles>
    <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarcjocalDataTemplate DataType="x:Static local:MyFiles" ItemSource="{Binding MyFiles}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding DisplayName}>
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding FullName}>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarcjocalDataTemplate>
    <TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

.cs:

```
fileList = new ObservableCollection<MyFiles>();
fileList.Add(new MyFiles("Test","TestPath"));
treeViewFiles.ItemSource = fileList;
```

And i got something like a list instead tree :\
How can i fix my code to get a real tree with root etc?
Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's going to be a plain list. Items do not know where they belong in the hierarchy. You need to have a tree structure in your code too.

Comment: It's not clear. How much level do you have? I see only one level, why do you need a treeview?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: Does your INotifyPropertyChanged work? I wouldn't think so... it should be getting "" for the property name every time since you aren't providing it. Maybe you forgot to add [CallerMemberName] to it? private void INofityPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName="")